# Two forms submit only one button javascript and open popup window

Tags: javascript, php, button

This is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submitButton").click(function () {
            var $form1 = $("#form1");
            $.post($form1.attr("action"), $form1.serialize(), 

        $('form[name="formsub"]').each(function () {
            var $form = $(this);
            $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), 
            })
        });
    });
</script>
<form id="form1" action="exam_fee_update1.php" method="post">
    // code
    </form>
    <form id="form2" action="exam_fee_update1.php" name= "formsub" method="post">   
     // code
</form>
```

When submit two forms data insert but I want after submit of two forms then open a popup window and display submit details..  help me.

Comment: maybe you should consider using preventDefault() after the click.

Comment: Where is the php code?

Comment: why you have 2 forms submitting to same URL. Put form2 code in form1.

Comment: first form is student regular exam fee and second form is student supple exam fee but both are insert one table so i use two forms.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery $.post throws a callback once the request is done:
after each form is submitted this will display the serialized contents:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#submitButton").click(function () {
        // serialize the two forms
        var formData = $('#form1, #form2').serialize();
        var formAction =  $('#form1').attr("action");
        $.post( formAction, formData, function(reply){
           // this will create a popup box within the browser and show you the details
           alert(formData);
        });
   }
)
```

If it's for debugging purposes you can use chrome dev tools under the network tab, you'll have to make sure you tick *preserve log* if the page reloads.

[image]

[image]

Comment: tacky answer if you don't know answer keep silent and don't post anything wrong

Comment: I just updated my answer and hopefully it's more inline with what you're after.